# How to plot a 2D mesh (not a meshgrid) with more than 4000 nodes efficiently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mesh

I have a Mesh class with node coordinates (coords) and element connectivities (connect) which works fine for elements with 150 nodes but takes long (> 10 seconds) for more than 1000 nodes (around 4000 elements). I made a very simple function using matplotlib.pyplot. Is there a more efficient way of plotting large datasets?

P.S. I am currently storing my coords and elements as lists but returning them as np.ndarray.

```
def plotMesh(self):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    coords = self.getCoords()

    for connect in self.connectivity:
        coords = self.getCoords(connect)
        ax.plot(coords[:,0],coords[:,1], linewidth = 0.5, color='k')

    plt.show()
```